# Angular Highcharts Wordcloud color array

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, word-cloud

I am using Angular Highcharts 9.1.0 and I am trying to generate a word cloud that uses specific colors. For some reason the colors in the array are not applying, see below:

```
this.options = {
   series: [{
      type: 'wordcloud',
      data,
      name: 'Occurrences',
      minFontSize: 12,
      maxFontSize: 42,
      colors: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue']
   }]
};
```

I have tried with Hex colors as well. I have found a way of doing it but I am not a fan of it. I can adjust the CSS properties with styled mode but it seems to generate 10 different classes (.highcharts-color-X where X is 0-9) and I have to adjust the colors accordingly which I am not a huge fan of because I can't control which words get what color and sometimes it feels like all the words have the same colors and it doesn't feel very random. I want to ideally have highcharts handle it but the above code does not seem to work. From the documentation, I need to make sure `colorByPoint` is true which, according to their docs, is true by default and regardless I have tried to manually set it with no luck.

Here is an example of the generated word cloud using those options:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define global Highcharts colors by using `setOptions` feature,
2. Set `colorByPoint` as true,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3mnjx79w/